# Create snippet with link to document

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-snippet

I create a custom models.Model and register to snippet.
I wish that this model have a field to a Wagtail document.

How can I do that ?

```
@register_snippet
class Product(Model):
     name = CharField(max_length=255)
     bill = ReferenceToWagtailDocument() <-- how to code that
```

Ideally, I wish that bill can be selectable in Wagtail Snippet.

Any idea to do that ?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by adding a ForeignKey like the following.

```
@register_snippet
class Product(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=255)
    bill = ForeignKey(Document, on_delete=CASCADE, null=True)
```

Hope that I can help somebody.

One drawback, I don't have the file selector.

Best regards.